# Simple way to use parameterised UI messages in Wicket?

Tags: java, internationalization, properties, wicket

Wicket has a [flexible internationalisation system](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization) that supports parameterising UI messages in many ways. There are examples e.g. in [StringResourceModel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/StringResourceModel.html) javadocs, such as this:

```
WeatherStation ws = new WeatherStation();
add(new Label("weatherMessage", new StringResourceModel(
    "weather.${currentStatus}", this, new Model<String>(ws)));
```

But I want something really **simple**, and couldn't find a good example of that.

Consider this kind of UI message in a .properties file:

```
msg=Value is {0}
```

Specifically, I wouldn't want to create a model object (with getters for the values to be replaced; like WeatherStation in the above example) only for this purpose. That's just overkill if I already have the values in local variables, and there is otherwise no need for such object.

Here's a stupid "brute force" way to replace the {0} with the right value:

```
String value = ... // contains the dynamic value to use
add(new Label("message", getString("msg").replaceAll("\\{0\\}", value)));
```

**Is there a clean, more Wicket-y way to do this** (that isn't awfully much longer than the above)**?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most consistent **WICKETY** way could be accomplished by improving [Jonik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976888/simple-way-to-use-parameterised-ui-messages-in-wicket/29862176#10249630) with [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

.properties:

```
msg=Saving record {0} with value {1}
```

.java:

```
add(new Label("label", MessageFormat.format(getString("msg"),obj1,obj2)));
//or
info(MessageFormat.format(getString("msg"),obj1,obj2));
```

Why I like it:

- Clean, simple solution
- Uses plain Java and nothing else
- You can replace as many values as you want
- Work with labels, info(), validation, etc.
- It's not completely wickety but it is consistent with wicket so you may reuse these properties with `StringResourceModel`.

Notes:

if you want to use Models you simply need to create a simple model that override `toString` function of the model like this:

```
abstract class MyModel extends AbstractReadOnlyModel{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if(getObject()==null)return "";
        return getObject().toString();
    }
}
```

and pass it as `MessageFormat` argument.

I don't know why Wicket does not support `Model` in feedback message. but if it was supported there was no reason to use these solutions and you could use `StringResourceModel` everywhere.

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is basically an improved version of `String.format()` [which I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249630/56285), with the key difference that `MessageFormat` truly supports many languages since the order of replaced parameters is explicitly specified.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at Example 4 in the StringResourceModel javadoc - you can pass a null model and explicit parameters:

```
add(new Label("message",
         new StringResourceModel(
             "msg", this, null, value)));

msg=Value is {0}
```

Comment: StringResourceModel doesn't have a constructor with more than 3 arguments in the current version 8.5.* .  Easiest way now:  MessageFormat.format(new StringResourceModel(MY_KEY).getString(), arg1, arg2, arg3);

Answer (score 5):

There's a way, which although still involves creating a model, doesn't requires a bean with a getter.

given this message in a properties file:

```
msg=${} persons
```

Here's how to replace the placeholder with a value, be it a local variable, a field or a literal:

```
add(new Label("label", new StringResourceModel("msg", new Model<Serializable>(5))));
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, do you know of any name for this `${}` notation, and is it documented somewhere? Would it be possible to replace more than one placeholder (something like `${0}` and `${1}`?) in a message using this approach?

Comment: ${} is simply shorthand for method calls against the model object itself. Don't know the name. ${} i believe just does model.toString(), but for things like convention-over-configuration of resource key names for page titles you can do something like "add( new Label( "title", new StringResourceModel( "${class.simpleName}.title", this, currentPageModel ) )"

Answer (score 2):

When faced with something like described in the question, I would now use:

.properties:

```
msg=Saving record %s with value %d
```

Java:

```
add(new Label("label", String.format(getString("msg"), record, value)));
```

Why I like it:

- Clean, simple solution
- Uses [plain Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and nothing else
- You can replace as many values as you want (unlike with the [`${}` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986316/56285)). **Edit**: well, if you actually need to support *many languages* where the replaced values might be in different order, `String.format()` is no good. Instead, [using MessageFormat is a similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862176/56285) that properly supports this.

Disclaimer: this is "too obvious", but it's simpler than the other solutions (and definitely nicer than my original `replaceAll()` hack). I originally sought for a "Wicket-y" way, while this kinda bypasses Wicket—then again, who cares? :-)

Comment: One more advantage: you can use the exact same approach for feedback messages (methods like info(), error() in Component and Session), lending consistency to your code. For example: `info(String.format(getString("events.created"), events.size()));`

Comment: You CAN have different order with %s solution:
msg=%2$s %1$s

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a Model in your Component which holds an object with values you want to access from your placeholders as substitutions, you can write:

```
new StringResourceModel("salutation.text", getModel());
```

Let's imagine `getModel()`'s return type is `IModel<User>` and `User` contains fields like `firstName` and `lastName`. In this case you can easily access `firstName` and `lastName` fields inside your property string:

```
salutation.text=Hej ${firstName} ${lastName}, have a nice day!
```

Further information you can find here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/model/StringResourceModel.html#StringResourceModel-java.lang.String-org.apache.wicket.model.IModel-

Comment: I think this is the pure wicket way of doing this task.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Model for your Label really is **The Wicket Way**. That said, you can make it easy on yourself with the occasional utility function. Here's one I use:

```
/**
 * Creates a resource-based label with fixed arguments that will never change. Arguments are wrapped inside of a
 * ConvertingModel to provide for automatic conversion and translation, if applicable.
 * 
 * @param The component id
 * @param resourceKey The StringResourceModel resource key to use
 * @param component The component from which the resourceKey should be resolved
 * @param args The values to use for StringResourceModel property substitutions ({0}, {1}, ...).
 * @return the new static label
 */
public static Label staticResourceLabel(String id, String resourceKey, Component component, Serializable... args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ConvertingModel<Serializable>[] models = new ConvertingModel[args.length];
    for ( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
        models[i] = new ConvertingModel<Serializable>( new Model<Serializable>( args[i] ), component );
    }
    return new CustomLabel( id, new StringResourceModel( resourceKey, component, null, models ) );
}
```

Details I'm glossing over here are:

1. I've created my own `ConvertingModel` which will automatically convert objects to their String representation based on the IConverters available to the given component
2. I've created my own `CustomLabel` that applies custom label text post-processing (as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387228/using-wicketmessage-tag-to-produce-partially-formatted-text/4391039#4391039))

With a custom IConverter for, say, a Temperature object, you could have something like:

```
Properties key:
temperature=The current temperature is ${0}.

Page.java code:
// Simpler version of method where wicket:id and resourceKey are the same
add( staticResourceLabel( "temperature", new Temperature(5, CELSIUS) ) );

Page.html:
<span wicket:id='temperature'>The current temperature is 5 degrees Celsius.</span>
```

The downside to this approach is that you no longer have direct access to the Label class, you can't subclass it to override `isVisible()` or things like that. But for my purposes it works 99% of the time.