# Wicket - strange behavior with parameterized StringResourceModel

Tags: java, internationalization, wicket, jodatime, wicket-1.5

This is my resource key:

```
Expired {0} days ago
```

This is the definition of the StringResourceModel:

```
new StringResourceModel("store.expired.tooltip", null, Days.daysBetween(expirationDate, refDate));
```

Expected result would be something like `Expired 20 days` ago but the actual result is `Expired P20D ago`.

Any idea what is causing this? I think I do [everything right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976888/simple-way-to-use-parameterised-ui-messages-in-wicket) but not sure.

Comment: What is `Days#daysBetween`? What does it return? If it returns an object, what class is it of, and does this class implement `toString()`?

Comment: @DonRoby: Yep, you just got my upvote! :)

Comment: And mine, also thank you npe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually an error in your usage of joda-time.  See the javadoc for joda [Days](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html).

`Days.daysBetween(expirationDate, refDate)` returns a joda `Days` object, whose `toString()` method returns ISO8601 duration format string, which is what you're seeing.

Using `Days.daysBetween(expirationDate, refDate).getDays()` instead will make it an integer, which should format correctly.

Comment: So focused on understanding the StringResourceModel that this never occurred to me; I just assumed it returned an int. Time to call it a day I think :-). Tx!